# How should I add text to my column's select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my sql code

```
SELECT sessionname, left(comment,4)) 
  FROM moma_reporting.comments where name like '%_2016_02_%'
  and comment = '1200'
```

My output will be :

```
"WE247JP_2016_02_07__14_48_18";"1200"
"FORD49_2016_02_03__12_42_24";"1200"
"1-GRB-804_2016_02_06__08_20_15";"1200"
```

What i want to do is to add text to column -comment so it will look like this:

```
"WE247JP_2016_02_07__14_48_18";"1200-QC"
"FORD49_2016_02_03__12_42_24";"1200-QC"
"1-GRB-804_2016_02_06__08_20_15";"1200-QC"
```

How i can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concat it:

```
SELECT sessionname, left(comment,4))||'-QC' 
FROM moma_reporting.comments 
where name like '%_2016_02_%'
  and comment = '1200'
```

---

Unrelated, but: `left(comment,4))` is useless. The condition `and comment = '1200'` will never return comments that are longer then 4 characters.

Comment: well this description was shortened by me. The full one is - 1200 - rejected by QC'

Comment: @WiktorKostrzewski: but the condition `comment = '1200'` won't return that. You need a `like` there as well.